# Sql query is giving error for dummy column in CASE condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have small query which have case and as per condition CASE produce a dummy col but its giving error

```
    Select Ad_Date,
    CASE 
WHEN Ad_DATE is null AND TRAN_DATE is null and Join_Date is not null THEN 'Approve-Pending' AS Status
WHEN Ad_DATE is null AND TRAN_DATE is null and Join_Date is null THEN 'Decline' AS Status
 from table1
```

Here Its giving error "Missing keyword" , and error coming before AS keyword

Comment: `END AS Status`

Comment: @jarlh if i have two WHEN condtions then in that case where to put END?

Comment: @jarlh i just updated the query , i have two When condition.please help me for the same.

Comment: You need to remove the first `AS Status` and replace the second one with `END AS Status`.

Answer (score 2):

A `case` expression returns a single value.  You can give this value a column alias, but that goes after the end of the expression.  `Case` expressions end with `end`.

So, this looks like:

```
Select Ad_Date,
       (case when Ad_DATE is null and TRAN_DATE is null and Join_Date is not null 
             then 'Approve-Pending'
             when Ad_DATE is null and TRAN_DATE is null and Join_Date is null 
             then 'Decline'
        end) as Status
from table1;
```

Note that this `case` expression does not have an `ELSE`.  So any rows that do not match the two conditions will have a value of `NULL` for status.

Comment: If i am using pipe to make output as pip seprated then and sql query is like  case is giving error,Do you have any idea about this?                                                                         Select '''' || Ad_Date|| ',"'
       (case when Ad_DATE is null and TRAN_DATE is null and Join_Date is not null 
             then 'Approve-Pending'
             when Ad_DATE is null and TRAN_DATE is null and Join_Date is null 
             then 'Decline'
        end) as Status || '","'
from table1;

Comment: @vim . . . This answers the question you have asked here.  If you have an additional question, ask it as a *question* not a comment.  I cannot read the code in the comment.

Comment: @vim . . . That invalidates my answer, which is impolite because it could attract downvotes.  You should ask a *new* question.